# loader-utils is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-vulnerabilities

I got some errors in my VSCode terminal in  my Angular App:

```
loader-utils  3.0.0 - 3.2.0
Severity: high
loader-utils is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) via url variable - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3rfm-jhwj-7488
loader-utils is vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hhq3-ff78-jv3g
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/loader-utils
  @angular-devkit/build-angular  13.0.0-next.0 - 13.3.9 || 14.0.0-next.0 - 14.2.9 || 15.0.0-next.0 - 15.0.0-rc.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

2 high severity vulnerabilities
```

I tried to use `npm audit fix` but didn't help.

How to fix it safely (I am quite new w Angular)?

I attach screenshot from terminal.[image]

Thank you for a help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your package-lock.json file change loader-utils version to 3.2.1. This issue has been patched in versions 1.4.2, 2.0.4 and 3.2.1, for Angular you use 3.2.1

`"loader-utils": "3.2.0", ==> "loader-utils": "3.2.1",`

Comment: thanks for response, I have already done it same way as you advised but got another issue and forget about to close this question.

Comment: Should I do anything after changing it in package-lock.json? I did it but it still occurs

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

Change package-lock.json to loader-utils version 3.2.1 as Stefan Nagirniak mentioned:

`"loader-utils": "3.2.0", ==> "loader-utils": "3.2.1",`
save changes

Then run npm audit fix in CLI again:

`npm audit fix`

(Sorry, not enough rep to reply with a comment on Stefan Nagirniak answer)

Answer (score 0):

A simple and easy way to solve this issue is, by running the following command in your project:

**`npm update loader-utils`**